# Extracting character from str and reformatting dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2017-1-1', '2017-1-2', '2017-1-3'],
    'Groups': [['one','two'], ['one','three'], 'four']})

    Date      Groups          
0  2017-1-1    one, two       
1  2017-1-2    one, three          
2  2017-1-3    four
```

How can I generate a new DataFrame like this?

```
    Date      Groups          one     two     three   four
0  2017-1-1    one, two       1        1        0       0
1  2017-1-2    one, three     1        0        1       0      
2  2017-1-3    four           0        0        0       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`join`** with **`get_dummies`**

```
df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.Groups.apply(pd.Series), prefix='', prefix_sep=''))

       Date        Groups  four  one  three  two
0  2017-1-1    [one, two]     0    1      0    1
1  2017-1-2  [one, three]     0    1      1    0
2  2017-1-3          four     1    0      0    0
```

Comment: Thanks. How can i remove square brackets in dataframe? The data I have doesn't have square brackets.